# Run a function after lit-element paint

Tags: typescript, lit-element

I'm looking to run a function after changes to two lit-elements have been painted/rendered to the screen.

I've come up with the following but I am wondering:
(a) is it correct? (have I used `requestAnimationFrame` correctly?)
(b) is there a better way?

```
changeElementPropertiesWhichCauseRedraw(this.ele1, this.ele2);

Promise.all([this.ele1.updateComplete, this.ele2.updateComplete])
  .then(() => window.requestAnimationFrame(() => setTimeout(() => afterPaint())));
```

Comment: It's not pretty, but to me, if it works, why not. Requestanimationframe is also used correctly imho, maybe setTimeout isn't needed, but sometimes it only works that way. Overall, I would rather have a parent component and change a property or state after updates are complete and react on that, probably in a lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, there is out-of-the-box lifecycle method that does exactly what you need.
In your lit-element component you need to implement the following:

```
  firstUpdated() {
    super.firstUpdated();
    // your code goes here
  }
```

Called when your element has rendered for the first time. Called once in the lifetime of an element. Useful for one-time setup work that requires access to the DOM.

Reference:
https://open-wc.org/guides/knowledge/lit-element/lifecycle/

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't account for all children elements. I've run into situations where  `firstUpdated` has completed, but a non web component child element hasn't completed rendering yet and returns `undefined` if you try to grab the element or an attribute, for example, and in that situation only an `updateComplete` can be used.

Comment: @JustinFormentin is also quite achievable. If you are using `lit-element` and you need to access a child element you can `await` for child element's `updateComplete`. If it's something other than `lit-element` you should refer to the component/framework docs and look up if something like `updateComplete` is available.

Comment: I'm talking about an element that is not a web component. I've run into problems where an `<input>` element that is a child of my web component wasn't loaded by the time the web component's `firstUpdated` has run, and returned undefined. Thus, the parent's `updateComplete` had to be used.